# Probot based GitHub app deployed as a docker container on AKS (Azure Kubernetes Service) cannot receive webhooks

Tags: dockerfile, azure-aks, nginx-ingress, github-app, probot

I wrote a GitHub app using Probot that I successfully tested locally using smee.io. I then tried to take my app into production by deploying it to a Kubernetes cluster as a docker container on AKS(Azure Kubernetes Service), setup an ingress to receive the webhooks from my app on the container but I keep seeing 404 error.

I used this [dockerfile](https://github.com/erickmendonca/probot-docker/blob/master/Dockerfile) as an example and was able to successfully build the image and push it to ACR (Azure Container Registry). Below is my dockerfile.

```
FROM my-image-registry/node:18-alpine3.16 as build

# set working directory 
WORKDIR /app/probot/

ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# install and cache app dependencies

COPY ./.npmrc ./
COPY ./package.json ./
# COPY ./tsconfig.json ./

RUN npm cache clean --force && npm install --force --loglevel verbose

FROM my-image-registry/node:18-alpine3.16 as app

WORKDIR /app/probot/

COPY --from=build /app/probot/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY . ./

RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 3005

COPY .env ./

#CMD npm run start
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

As my next step I deployed the container to Kubernetes using kubectl and I am able to have it up and running successfully. Below is my kubectl inline configuration.

```
---
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  labels:
    app: probot-service
  name: my-app-pod
  namespace: my-namespace
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: probot-service
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: probot-service
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: probot-service
          image: myacrurl/my-app-docker-image:d1.0
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3005
      nodeSelector:
        agentpool: apppool

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: probot-service
  name: probot-service
  namespace: my-namespace
spec:
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      targetPort: 3005
    - name: https
      protocol: TCP
      port: 443
      targetPort: 3005
  selector:
    app: probot-service
  type: ClusterIP
```

When I run `Kubectl logs <podname> -n <namespace>`, I see the message

```
INFO (server): Running Probot v13.0.2 (Node.js: v18.8.0)
INFO (server): Listening on http://localhost:3005
```

I have setup an ingress to have the webhooks from my app routed to the container. Below is my ingress configuration

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: probot-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: 'true'
spec:
  rules:
  - host: probot.mydomain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: /probot(/|$)(.*)
        backend:
          service:
            name: probot-service
            port:
              number: 80
```

I have tried hardcoding my app id, webhook secret, installation ID and other required parameters for my probot app. I tried adding them environment variables. I tried copying the .env file to the docker image during image creation and nothing seems to work.

What could I be doing wrong? Is it even possible to deploy probot apps on AKS?

Answer (score 0):

One key part of the issue is: `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx`.
This is a deprecated annotation. Should use `spec.ingressClassName: nginx` instead. Check [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-basic#create-an-ingress-route) for demo ingress yaml.

**Note:** `nginx-ingress` only loads your ingress by specific keyword. So this is one of the reasons why it is not working.

---

The second issue is: `INFO (server): Listening on http://localhost:3005`.
**In simple:** listen on `0.0.0.0` instead.

An example:

```
2c2d4a84d354:/# kubectl get po -o wide
NAME                      READY STATUS   RESTARTS AGE   IP           NODE                            NOMINATED NODE READINESS GATES
my-nginx-79b55879bb-7kzgz 1/1   Running  0        3m10s 198.18.4.15  aks-userpool-123456-vmss000006  <none>         <none>
my-nginx-79b55879bb-mqv7d 1/1   Running  0        116s  198.18.1.244 aks-userpool-123456-vmss000000  <none>         <none>
```

Go inside the Pod `my-nginx-79b55879bb-7kzgz`, and configured nginx conf like below:

```
listen       80;
listen  [::]:80;
listen       localhost:8000;
server_name  localhost;
```

Check listen status in Pod:

```
root@my-nginx-79b55879bb-7kzgz:/# lsof -i:80 && lsof -i:8000
COMMAND PID USER   FD   TYPE  DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
nginx     1 root    6u  IPv4 4425979      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
nginx     1 root    7u  IPv6 4425980      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
COMMAND PID USER   FD   TYPE  DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
nginx     1 root   13u  IPv6 4462662      0t0  TCP localhost:8000 (LISTEN)
nginx     1 root   14u  IPv4 4462663      0t0  TCP localhost:8000 (LISTEN)
```

Let's go inside the other Pod and curl this Pod:

```
root@my-nginx-79b55879bb-mqv7d:/# curl 198.18.4.15:8000 --head
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 198.18.4.15 port 8000 after 1 ms: Couldn't connect to server
root@my-nginx-79b55879bb-mqv7d:/# curl 198.18.4.15:80 --head
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.25.4
Date: Fri, 01 Mar 2024 09:01:26 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 615
Last-Modified: Wed, 14 Feb 2024 16:03:00 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
ETag: "65cce434-267"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

In conclusion, binding listener to `localhost` **make your backend not accessible from outside of the Pod**.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I did correct the annotations soon after I posted the question but I still have the same issue. Binding the listener to localhost shouldn't be an issue because my pod is in a Kubernetes cluster and the service has a cluster IP which would still allow traffic from outside the pod.

Comment: @ManiShankar Service Cluster IP is just an IP redirect your traffic to endpoint IPs (aka Pod IPs). So if you cannot connect to Pod, you cannot connect to svc cluster IP. A simple example: if you listen your service on a normal Virtual Machine and listen on localhost, no out traffic will go inside since you listen on the wrong address. (This restriction is not being made by Kubernetes but the basic mechanism.)
Simply listen on 0.0.0.0 and see if it works.